# Does Asuna speak English?

Tags: sword-art-online

In episode 5 of the English sub of Sword Art Online: Alicization, Asuna infiltrates the Ocean Turtle facility disguised as Mayumi Reynolds.

When she arrives at the facility, she says "nice to meet you" to the guard who greets her in English. Further in, when another guard asks her to remove her sunglasses and confirm her identity, she replies "sure" in English.

Does Asuna have any significant English speaking ability? Or did she simply learn a few words in order to solidify her disguise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yuuki Asuna went to an [all girls private school](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuki_Asuna) before the events of SAO. So I'm pretty sure she would have learned it at her school during that time. Most Japanese schools teach [English as a curriculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_education_in_Japan). But sadly a lot of Japanese people still don't have "fluent English conversation abilities".

Considering how serious she was about clearing the game, I would guess that she probably also took her school work very seriously. And hence most definitely picked up the lot of the English phrases which she then used in SAO.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Rumplestiltskin's answer, Asuna was raised in a strict environment by her parents, particularly, her mother. In the novel, there was a scene where her mother was angry with her and ban her from playing games so that she can study more (although she is not lagging behind in her study).

Because of this, I'm sure that Asuna is fluent in English. At least for a Japanese she is fluent. By that I mean her English would possibly still have a heavy Japanese accent.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else she learned on the helicopter ride to Rath, I’m sure she and Rinko has a plan, as she was studying in California I’m sure two quick sentences were discussed as it was a huge ruse to get Asuna back to the love of her life